# How can I create a new wordpress post from within NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wp-api

I'm trying to access my WordPress site from a NodeJS program. Specifically, I'm trying to create a draft post from within a NodeJS program. I've never done this before, and I can't get it work.

I've tried a few ways of doing this. First I used WPAPI and went through the documentation for that. It seemed to connect and get a response from my site but no post was created.

**WPAPI method and response log**

I've gotten an application password through the Wordpress control panel and I'm using it in the program. The username is from the same page on my panel.

I had installed the JSON Basic Authentication plugin while working with WPAPI, but I deactivated it when I switched to another method.

(Following the documentation on GitHub for WPAPI, I thought I would need to install the superagent bundle so I could use `create()` I tried installing superagent, requiring wpapi/superagent, and changing the type to module in the package, but when I tried to run it I got an error message saying the module "wpapi/superagent" could not be found. After that I just went back to the general import.)

```
import WPAPI from "wpapi"

const wp = new WPAPI({
    endpoint: 'https://www.example.com/wp-json',
    username: 'username',
    password: 'application_password'
})

wp.posts().create({
    title: 'test post',
    content: 'will this work?'
}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
})
```

The log:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    date: '2022-09-11T22:33:39',
    date_gmt: '2022-09-11T22:33:39',
    guid: { rendered: 'https://example.com/?p=1' },
    modified: '2022-09-11T22:33:39',
    modified_gmt: '2022-09-11T22:33:39',
    slug: 'hello-world',
    status: 'publish',
    type: 'post',
    link: 'https://example.com/2022/09/11/hello-world/',
    title: { rendered: 'Hello world!' },
    content: {
      rendered: '\n' +
        '<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\n', 
      protected: false
    },
    excerpt: {
      rendered: '<p>Welcome to WordPress. This is your first post. Edit or delete it, then start writing!</p>\n',
      protected: false
    },
    author: 1,
    featured_media: 0,
    comment_status: 'open',
    ping_status: 'open',
    sticky: false,
    template: '',
    format: 'standard',
    meta: {
      bgseo_title: '',
      bgseo_description: '',
      bgseo_robots_index: '',
      bgseo_robots_follow: ''
    },
    categories: [ 1 ],
    tags: [],
    aioseo_notices: [],
    _links: {
      self: [Array],
      collection: [Array],
      about: [Array],
      author: [Array],
      replies: [Array],
      'version-history': [Array],
      'wp:attachment': [Array],
      'wp:term': [Array],
      curies: [Array]
    }
  },
  _paging: {
    total: 1,
    totalPages: 1,
    links: { 'https://api.w.org/': 'https://example.com/wp-json/' }
  }
]
```

**Using Fetch to send the post**

Now I'm trying code from a guide I found on Medium, and I'm having pretty much the same problem.
I receive a response that I believe means the connection was successful, but no posts have been created on my site, draft or otherwise.

Here's the code:

```
import fetch from "node-fetch"


const createdPost = await fetch(`https://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from("username:application_password", "utf-8").toString("base64")}`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      title: 'New post title',
      content: 'New content'
    })
  })
  console.log(createdPost)
```

And this is what is logged:

```
Response {
  size: 0,
  [Symbol(Body internals)]: {
    body: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 6,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
    },
    stream: PassThrough {
      _readableState: [ReadableState],
      _events: [Object: null prototype],
      _eventsCount: 6,
      _maxListeners: undefined,
      _writableState: [WritableState],
      allowHalfOpen: true,
      [Symbol(kCapture)]: false,
      [Symbol(kCallback)]: null
    },
    boundary: null,
    disturbed: false,
    error: null
  },
  [Symbol(Response internals)]: {
    type: 'default',
    url: 'https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts',
    status: 200,
    statusText: 'OK',
    headers: {
      'access-control-allow-headers': 'Authorization, X-WP-Nonce, Content-Disposition, Content-MD5, Content-Type',
      'access-control-expose-headers': 'X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages, Link',
      allow: 'GET',
      'cache-control': 'max-age=172800',
      connection: 'Upgrade, close',
      'content-type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      date: 'Mon, 03 Oct 2022 14:43:35 GMT',
      expires: 'Wed, 05 Oct 2022 14:43:35 GMT',
      link: '<https://example.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"',
      server: 'Apache',
      'transfer-encoding': 'chunked',
      upgrade: 'h2',
      vary: 'Accept-Encoding,Cookie,Origin,User-Agent',
      'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
      'x-robots-tag': 'noindex',
      'x-wp-total': '1',
      'x-wp-totalpages': '1'
    },
    counter: 1,
    highWaterMark: 16384
  }
}
```

**Summary**

Both methods seem to connect but no post is created on my site. Can anyone help? I'm stuck and would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you were able to figure this out but I had success creating a new post using node-fetch so attaching a snippet of my code here:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const url = 'https://MY_HOSTNAME/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';

export const uploadWP = async ({ title, content }: {title: string, content: string}) => {
  // token is a combination of username and application password which was generated from the wp admin dashboard (in my user profile)
  const token = Buffer.from('cseo:XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX XXXX', 'utf-8').toString('base64');
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Authorization: `Basic ${token}`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        title,
        content,
        status: 'draft'
      })
  });

  const responseBody = await response.text();
  console.log('response', responseBody);
}

if (require.main === module) {
  const articles = require('../migration/json/articles.json');
  const article = articles.articles?.[0];
  uploadWP({ title: article.title, content: article.htmlBody });
}
```

It's baffling as my code is nearly identical to yours..? I'm not sure if not having a status in the content body ('published', 'draft' etc. [docs here](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#create-a-post)) was your issue? (I'm assuming you use an actual username and password combo in the your real code). But just leaving this here for your reference.